# Show text from a box using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm now learning JS, and met a simple problem of script writing.

[Here is a JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ninuza/1/edit?html,js,output)

```js
document.getElementById("sender").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("queryDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("queryDiv").innerHTML + document.getElementById("query").innerHTML;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type text here" id="query"></input>
  <button id="sender">send</button>
  <div id="queryDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

1. How to show the text next to the box where I can type things in?
2. In addition, what's the code to eliminate the text in the box after sending it?

Comment: WTH does this have to do with functional programming?

Comment: I'm still practicing JS. So I'd like to know how to do with it.:)

Comment: @Bergi You can give me some different methods for the same result. I appreciate it.

Comment: I meant that functional programming is not a tool that can be used to solve your problem.

Comment: Oops... I didn't know that. So should I use something for "query" alike? Sorry I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this code appears in script tags after the html elements you want to use.

```
document.getElementById("sender").addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("queryDiv").innerHTML += document.getElementById("query").value;
    document.getElementById("query").value = "";

});
```